# How to pass value and run c program in php( web application)

Tags: php, c++, c

I am having big `c` program.I want execute that function in php and get value

For example

C program

```
int add( int, int);         

void main()
{
  int i=1;
  printf("i starts out life as %d.", i);

  i = add(5, 10);           

  printf(" And becomes %d after function is executed.\n", i);
}


int add( int a, int b)          
{
  int c;
  c = a + b;
  return c;
}
```

my web form has value a and b. so when i submit form i want to call the c function add and
get the output.

I know there is a function to execute external programs in php
like

```
exec()
shell_exec()
```

But i am not familiar with this functions.so please give me sample of code. Should i place the c program file(in notepad) in server root folder.

Please guide me !
Thanks in advance

Comment: Things don't work like that. You need to structure your C application to parse input and then process it and return results. You can't just call C code from PHP.

Comment: @Alin:How can i do that i am good with c . can give me piece of code and instruction

Comment: @gwori: Simlpest solutions are to send the parameters as command line arguments or send them via stdin. Other approaches would be to write the C program as a socket daemon and run the PHP code as a client or implement a PHP extension in C. But the latter 2 methods are a lot more complex

Comment: A small correction. As @symcbean pointed out, you can call C code from PHP if you put it inside an extension. But I doubt this should be done in your particular situation.

Answer (score 6):

I guess the simplest way would be to call your C from PHP, passing the
parameters as arguments. On the C side:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = add(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2]));
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

(obviously, you should add error checking). On the PHP side:

```
$a = ...;
$b = ...;
$c = exec("/path/to/sum $a $b");
```

assuming your C program is called sum.

---

**Edit:** Just adding a comment about the various approaches that have
been suggested to you so far:

- Starting your C program with `exec()`, as in my answer above, is
  really the simplest solution. However, it costs you the creation of a
  new process every time you call your C code, which can be expensive
  if you do it a lot.
- A PHP extension spares the process creation and should be more
  efficient, especially if you are making many calls to your C code and
  your C code is fast to compute the result.
- A daemon is more interesting if your C program is slow to startup
  (long initialization) but can then process queries fast.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do that - but it's not trivial by any means.  You need to write a php extension in c/c++, install it on the server where the php will be executed and update you php.ini - and then you'll have access to the c/c++ functions directly from php.  Have a look here: http://devzone.zend.com/article/1021 about how to write extensions.

Comment: Linkrot : http://devzone.zend.com/article/1021...  but this approaches the subject : https://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.ze1.zendapi.php