# Rendering with OpenGL on a web server

Tags: c++, opengl

I have an application that runs on Nintendo 3DS -- it uses a variant of OpenGL to render 3D animation.  The user is able to store these scenes online as data files.  That is, only the data needed to render the scene is stored - the image frames are rendered on the device.

Additionally I would like for people to be able to view these scenes online.  One way might be to render them in the browser via WebGL, but I'm worried about the amount of time and memory this would require.  I would rather have the server render the scenes into movie files which can be played from a web page.

I don't have a lot of experience with server side programming - is it possible for a server program to render frames to an OpenGL context?  They would be offscreen framebuffers since there is no screen.

Any suggestions on an approach to doing that?  I've used PHP mostly for web programming, but it seems like that is not feasible for this.  Ideally I'd like to write a C++ program which ran on the server, that way I could re-use code from the 3DS.  Is that possible?  Where can I read about doing this?

Comment: In general client side rendering will always beat server side rendering regarding responsiveness and even more so server resource utilization. Also depending on the complexity of your artwork assets the bandwidth consumption of a video stream may break even rather quickly (or not, depending on what you need to transfer). As a customer/user I'd prefer the game to run locally.

Answer (score 2):

Server-side rendering is possible, and would provide more consistent results to the user than relying on consistent WebGL behavior across different browsers and platforms (as well as the time/memory performance concerns you already mentioned).  Users with capable browsers and platforms will not get any benefits, so you'll want to consider what your users want and the platforms they're using.

For Windows-based servers, using OpenGL (w/offscreen framebuffers) with "no screen" will present a challenge.  You need to start with a window to establish a graphics context.  (There may be a provision to establish a "windowless" graphics context for Linux.)  You also will need to determine how to manage any GPU resources for rendering, as it will have limits on the number of concurrent rendering requests it can support before slowing down and/or failing to allocate resources (e.g. framebuffer memory).

One alternative might be to use [Mesa](http://www.mesa3d.org/intro.html) (software OpenGL) implementation - this won't be as fast, but in theory, this would scale with added server CPU and memory, which matches how most web servers scale out: [Mesa offscreen rendering info](http://www.mesa3d.org/osmesa.html)

It looks like once written, spawning the [C++ executable with args from PHP is trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704079/how-to-pass-value-and-run-c-program-in-php-web-application) - although you may wish to route any long-running renderings to a separate rendering server to keep your web server responsive.